# How to make "case 3" into some sort of "case random"

Tags: javascript

I'm completing something for an assignment in my coding course, but I am stuck on a part of trying to set a number to random. Also, there are 3 blocks that have this, except the last block does not have an event.stopPropagation();.

I have tried setting "case 3" (which needs to be edited to something else) to "case random" but that did not work. It would only make it so that anything you would type in the prompt() would display the "You got it!" message.

```
...
alert( "Guess the number I'm thinking. It's between 1 and 5. You have 3 tries." )   

var min = 1;
var max = 5;
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
prompt( "You have 3 tries remaning." );
switch ( random )
{
    case 3:     alert( "You got it!");
    event.stopPropagation();

    break;

    default:    alert( "That is incorrect. Try again." );

    break;
}
...
```

I expect it to set a random (whole) number and have the user able to guess it, and have it validate properly.
Also, if there is anything else wrong with this block of code, could you please help me?

Comment: You never ask for the user's input.

Comment: There's little point in using `switch` for this, just use `if/else`.

Comment: What event listener is thise part of, and why do you need to stop propagation when the user guesses correctly?

Comment: As a side note, `random` is an awful variable name, given that there is already `Math.random()`; `numberToGuess`, say, avoids the clash and is more descriptive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the user's input - the `prompt` is an orphaned expression.

```
var guess = +prompt(...);
```

Then switch on the `guess`:

```
switch(guess) {
  case random:
    alert("You got it!");
    event.stopPropagation();
    break;
  default:
    alert("That is incorrect. Try again");
    break;
}
```

Switching isn't the best practice here however - as Barmar points out, an `if` is better and easier:

```
if (guess == random) {
  alert("You got it!");
  event.stopPropagation();
} else {
  alert("That is incorrect. Try again");
}
```

Comment: If there's just two cases this should just be an `if`.

Comment: Edited @Barmar.

Comment: Well the first idea of the switch(guess) is working, and validating properly in my code.